# Get order shipping tax percent in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, tax, shipping-tax

Since the order method `getFullTaxInfo()` is not available in Magento 2, how does one get the tax percent used on the order shipping amount for an order?

I see the item is in `sales_order_tax_item` table (where taxable_item_type = shipping), but I don't see any method in the Order or OrderInterface for fetching the tax details, except what is already in the Order table columns (tax amount, etc.). 
Weirdly enough this table also does not contain an order_id column, so there's no direct back-reference.

I know you can calculate the percentage manually but I think it's best to avoid it.

I see a promising method

`\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Tax::getTaxItemsByOrderId($orderId)`

but I have no idea how to properly use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out... Here's an example.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Tax\Item;

class APIHelper extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Tax\Item
     */
    protected $taxItem;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Item $taxItem
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->taxItem = $taxItem;
    }

    public function someMethod(OrderInterface $order)
    {
        $tax_items = $this->taxItem->getTaxItemsByOrderId($order->getId());
        var_dump($tax_items);
    }
}
```

Returns an array in format:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      'tax_id' => string '9' (length=1)
      'tax_percent' => string '22.0000' (length=7)
      'item_id' => null
      'taxable_item_type' => string 'shipping' (length=8)
      'associated_item_id' => null
      'real_amount' => string '1.1000' (length=6)
      'real_base_amount' => string '1.1000' (length=6)
      'code' => string 'Slovenia (standard)' (length=19)
      'title' => string 'Slovenia (standard)' (length=19)
      'order_id' => string '22' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=10)
      'tax_id' => string '9' (length=1)
      'tax_percent' => string '22.0000' (length=7)
      'item_id' => string '35' (length=2)
      'taxable_item_type' => string 'product' (length=7)
      'associated_item_id' => null
      'real_amount' => string '9.9000' (length=6)
      'real_base_amount' => string '9.9000' (length=6)
      'code' => string 'Slovenia (standard)' (length=19)
      'title' => string 'Slovenia (standard)' (length=19)
      'order_id' => string '22' (length=2)
```

So just iterate through and test if `taxable_item_type` equals to 'shipping':

```
    if (is_array($tax_items)) {
        foreach ($tax_items as $item) {
            if ($item['taxable_item_type'] === 'shipping') {
                // You got it
            }
        }
    }
```

I also had to recompile DI with `setup:di:compile` in CLI.

Comment: Great answer. Just one thing to look out for. Return will be an empty array if no tax was charged e.g. international order that doesn't attract local taxes. In that case there are no tax items for the order.