# Magento 2 - Getting an order item tax percentage

Tags: magento2, orders, tax, order-items

I need to get an order item tax percentage

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Plugin;


class myClass
{
    protected $_orderRepository;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    ) {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    public function processOrder($orderId)
    {
        $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);
        foreach ($order->getItems() as $item) {
            var_dump($item->getTaxPercent());
        }
    }
}
```

I always get the value of 0.00 even though I know the percentage is 20.00.

Could anyone advise how I should get the tax percentage

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. It will help you to get Tax Percent amount.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Tax\Item;

class APIHelper extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Tax\Item
     */
    protected $taxItem;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Item $taxItem
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->taxItem = $taxItem;
    }

    public function someMethod(OrderInterface $order)
    {
        $tax_items = $this->taxItem->getTaxItemsByOrderId($order->getId());
        var_dump($tax_items);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea I saw the post in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202746/get-order-shipping-tax-percent-in-magento-2 but I was hoping I could just get the percentage without looping around arrays and cross referencing products

Comment: If you want to get Tax percent by each order item then you have to go through loop. In your code you are doing the same thing.

Comment: Figured out my issue, my product was a configurable product and I needed to get the parent's tax percentage

Answer (score 1):

Without loop you can get tax by following code :

```
$invoiceItem->getOrderItem()->getTaxPercent()
```

It will return tax by order Item.

Answer (score 0):

change from:

```
foreach ($order->getItems() as $item) {
        var_dump($item->getTaxPercent());
    }
```

to:

```
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        var_dump($item->getTaxPercent());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple service that returns the tax percent by order ID.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Service\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

/**
 * Class GetOrderTaxPercentageService
 */
class GetOrderTaxPercentageService
{
    /**
     * Sales order tax table
     */
    private const SALES_ORDER_TAX_TABLE = 'sales_order_tax';

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resourceConnection;

    /**
     * GetNotScheduledCustomersToExport constructor.
     *
     * @param ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
     */
    public function __construct(
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
    ) {
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
    }

    /**
     * Get order tax percent
     *
     * @param int $orderId
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function execute(int $orderId): float
    {
        $table = $this->resourceConnection->getTableName(self::SALES_ORDER_TAX_TABLE);
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $select = $connection->select();
        $select->from(['order_tax' => $table], ['percent' => 'order_tax.percent']);
        $select->where('order_tax.order_id = ?', $orderId);
        $percent = (float) $connection->fetchOne($select);

        return (float) ($percent ? $percent/100 : 0.0);
    }
}
```