# Getting code or percent from sales_order_tax on order

Tags: magento2, tax

Magento 2 saves data in a 'sales_order_tax' table per transaction. I need to get the tax code and tax percent from this table for each order; however I can't find methods to do so? $order->getTaxPercent() would be obvious, but this does not work.

I do not need or want the tax percentage at an item level; just the tax rate on an order based on shipping address.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 1 you would have done this with `getFullTaxInfo()` but since it is not available in Magento 2. You have to get tax at item level and iterate through those to get shipping items.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$taxItems = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Tax\Item');
$orderTaxItems = $taxItems->getTaxItemsByOrderId('1'); // Your Order Id

if (is_array($orderTaxItems)) {
        foreach ($orderTaxItems as $item) {
            if ($item['taxable_item_type'] === 'shipping') {
                // Your Order Tax Item for Shipping
            }
        }
    }
```

For more reference in implementation please [refer here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/203471/77673).
Hope it finds helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your class where you need to retrieve the tax percent

```
private $taxCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
.....
\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Tax\CollectionFactory $taxCollectionFactory,
...
) {
   ....
    $this->taxCollectionFactory = $taxCollectionFactory;
   ...
}
```

then you can get all the taxes and tax percents applied to the order like this:
Assuming you have the `$order` object

```
$taxes = $this->taxCollectionFactory->create()->loadByOrder($order);
```

Now you can loop through the taxes and get all the percentages:

```
foreach ($taxes as $tax) {
   //do something with $tax->getPercent();
   //or $tax->getAmount();
}
```

You will always gets a collection because you can have multiple taxes applied to the order. If you are sure you only have one tax configured you can use `$taxes->getFirstItem()` in the code above and get the first element of the collection.

Comment: the method getByOrder() doesn't exist in Magento 2.3

Comment: yeah, it's called `loadByOrder` sorry about that