# Magento 2 how to get tax percentage for the shipping from order object

Tags: magento2

How we can get the tax percentage or tax class from the order object like `$order` in Magento 2.

Answer (score 2):

Tax rate is not based on order but on order item you can check these:

```
$orderItem->getTaxPercent();
```

For this you have to load orderitem object for it.

For invoice items associated order item by call

```
$invoiceItem->getOrderItem()->getTaxPercent()
```

For this you have to load orderitem object

also you may use like this : `$order->getFullTaxInfo();` for getting whole information.

Comment: what about this approach mentioned in this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202746/get-order-shipping-tax-percent-in-magento-2  ?

Comment: yes this is also useful for you

Comment: So what if i have more than 50 products in the cart then it loop for 50 items to match the taxable_item_type=='shipping' ?